# Sharepoint 2010 - Access to lists and alerts

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a list and added some fields in order to use it as a form.
We have 30 stores in the country and each store has its own login.

Every store need to be able to Create new items in the list and modify ONLY THEIR OWN.
In order to do that, I had used the LIST PARAMETER - ADVANCED - Read only element create by user.
BUT by doing that, I am unable to Create ALERTS!

So basically, I am looking for a way that users can Create a new entry in the list.
They can modify and see ONLY their entries. Using a custom view is not really a security method.

Administrator needs to see all of the entries and be able to modify any as well.

Form1 - User1
Form2 - User2

If Form1 is modified, I want only User1 (and admin) to be alerted.

Thank you very much and ask me if I forgot to mention any required piece of information

Comment: This question was asked already here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9420/is-there-a-workaround-for-the-you-cannot-create-alerts-for-lists-for-which-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Workflow... configure it to start when the item is modified... then in your Workflow you add 'Send email notification' step...

so it will be started when someone modify it, and will send you an email notification...